# Laravel Call to undefined method when i try access to function in class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

after implementing `ACL` on laravel i want to use `sync` to attach some permissions to user, when i try to use this code:

```
Route::get('/setPermission', function () {
    //auth()->loginUsingId(1);

    return \App\Role::whereName('admin')->permissions()->sync(
        [
            1, 2
        ]
    );
});
```

I get this error:

```
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::permissions()"
```

my `Role` class:

```
class Role extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['name','label'];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function permissions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }
}
```

`Permission` class:

```
class Permission extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['name','label'];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}
```

result of get `Roles` of user:

```
[{"id":2,"name":"admin","label":"\u0645\u062f\u06cc\u0631 \u06a9\u0644 \u0633\u0627\u06cc\u062a \u0648 \u0633\u06cc\u0633\u062a\u0645","created_at":"2017-12-21 07:44:09","updated_at":"2017-12-21 07:44:09"}]
```

Comment: can you show us the `whereName` function?

Comment: @Wreigh yes i dont have problem for show `whereName`

Comment: ok, please update your question to include the `whereName` function :)

Comment: @Wreigh result of `whereName` ?

Comment: no, the function itself bro.

Comment: @Wreigh `whereName` is for laravel query builder, i dont understand me

Comment: that's the reason for the error, `whereName` returns a QueryBuilder, not a *Role* Model which has the function **permissions**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161685/discussion-between-mahdi-pishguy-and-wreigh).

Answer (score 1):

problem resolved by this code:

adding `->first()` after `whereName`

```
Route::get('/setPermission', function () {
    //auth()->loginUsingId(1);

    return \App\Role::whereName('admin')->first()->permissions()->sync(
        [
            1, 2
        ]
    );
});
```